# how to remove duplicates in an integer array? using Java

Tags: java

I have an integer array sorted in descending order, and I have to remove duplicate elements and return remaining values from the array (without using java Collections).

ex:This is my array,

```
int a[]={12,12,8,6,4,4,2,1}
```

and The o/p should be,

```
{8,6,2,1}
```

how to achieve this using Java?

Comment: Can you share the code you've written so far and where you got stuck?

Comment: how to achieve this using Java? - write some code.

Answer (score -2):

here's the code

```
public static int[] removeDuplicates(int []s){
    int result[] = new int[s.length], j=0;
    for (int i : s) {
        if(!isExists(result, i))
            result[j++] = i;
    }
    return result;
}
private static boolean isExists(int[] array, int value){
    for (int i : array) {
        if(i==value)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```